# RSS feeds regularly send glut of wrong messages

Tags: bug, status-review, rss

We use the RSS feed integration in Slack to see relevant posts on Stack Overflow and respond to them in a timely fashion.

However, on a fairly regular basis (perhaps every few weeks?) a sudden flood of unrelated questions come through into the channel.

Here are the exact details of the most recent flood:

- Feed URL: https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=cics&sort=newest
- Time: 16:12:39-16:12:40 UTC
- Incorrectly pushed posts:

  - [Import Firebase DB from same region Bucket fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77354681/import-firebase-db-from-same-region-bucket-fails)
  - [Installing 'gcloud' inside Go Docker image, cannot find Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77355257/installing-gcloud-inside-golang-docker-image-cannot-find-python)
  - [Access cross GCP projects with one shared service account credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77356603/access-cross-gcp-projects-with-one-shared-service-account-credentials)
  - [Permission denied on CloudTasksClient.create_task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77368033/permission-denied-on-cloudtasksclient-create-task)
  - [What is the difference between Firebase Hosting and Google App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77369952/what-is-the-difference-between-firebase-hosting-and-google-app-engine)
  - [ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.delete) Could not fetch resource: The resource not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77376775/error-gcloud-compute-instances-delete-could-not-fetch-resource-the-resource)
  - [CLI gcloud - The following signatures could not be verified because their public key is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77385641/cli-gcloud-the-following-signatures-could-not-be-verified-because-their-public)
  - [Need to install ops agent using gcloud python sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77394177/need-to-install-ops-agent-using-gcloud-python-sdk)
  - [gcloud cronjob to copy DB data from DB hosted in docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77395116/gcloud-cronjob-to-copy-db-data-from-db-hosted-in-docker-container)
  - [Python, Poetry, cant publish to Google Artifact Registry repository | 'The request does not have valid authentication credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77397920/python-poetry-cant-publish-to-google-artifact-registry-repository-the-reque)
  - [What am I doing wrong with gcloud scp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77398123/what-am-i-doing-wrong-with-gcloud-scp)
  - [How can I find the python client library for a gcloud command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77398366/how-can-i-find-the-python-client-library-for-a-gcloud-command)
  - [gcloud get-iam-policy not showing full list of principals and their roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77401624/gcloud-get-iam-policy-not-showing-full-list-of-principals-and-their-roles)
  - [cloud sdk not signed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77415703/cloud-sdk-not-signed)

It would be great for this to be fixed—it's making some of the channel membership debate whether we should remove the integration, which would stop us being able to help the SO membership so easily.

Comment: Related on MSE: [RSS feeds returning wrong tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/385546)

Comment: The common thread to all of this is that these questions are a part of the Google Cloud collective.  I wonder if somehow that's causing this issue.

Comment: The [CICS tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cics).

Comment: We've just had over 20 more pushed, this time all from the 'python' tag.

Comment: Another burst at 01:32:38 GMT on 14 Nov, this time all tagged 'minecraft-forge'.

Comment: Another burst of 29 messages at 14:22:35 GMT on 26 Nov. No particular tag in common that I can see.